# IOS not receiving firebase notification via fcm but only on ANDROID

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification

Can anyone help me why is my iOS device cannot receive any trigger whenever I test push notifications via fcm? compared to android, everything is working fine. here is a photo where I already enabled my Xcode configurations. This is the link where I followed the integrations and setup https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky...

Assuming you set up everything else correctly as per the [Apple integration docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration)...

- First, you cannot run on iOS Simulators:

> FCM via APNs does not work on iOS Simulators. To receive messages &
> notifications a real device is required.

source: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration

- Then, in my experience, iOS and Android use different format for the FCM load. Something like this should work

```
          // CONSTRUCT NOTIFICATION PAYLOAD 
          message = {
            "notification": {
              "body": body,
            },
            // apple push notification service
            "apns": {
              "payload":
              {
                "aps": {
                  "alert": {
                    "body": body,
                  },
                  "sound": "default",
                },
              }
            },
            token: fcmToken,
          };
```

see: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

see also: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#ApnsConfig